# Django 2.0 Password Validation

Tags: python, regex, django

By default in Django 2.0 we get **AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS** option with

- UserAttributeSimilarityValidator
- MinimumLengthValidator
- CommonPasswordValidator
- NumericPasswordValidator

So is there any easy way to add extra VALIDATORS like minimum 1 uppercase, 1 symbol, 1 digit, etc. ?

In python I can check Using **regex**

```
import re
userPass = 'HelloWorld*123'
if re.search('[A-Z]', userPass)!=None and re.search('[0-9]', userPass)!=None and re.search('[^A-Za-z0-9]', userPass)!=None:
    print 'Strong Password'
```

Comment: create custom user model and add your regex to model as validators to field

Comment: I am using instance of AbstractUser for User model, so now tell me do i need to add field with same name to override pre-exist field ??

Comment: yes you should, that's why we create custom user model

Comment: You don't need a custom user model for that. Just [write your own password validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator) and add it to the `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`.

Comment: I am using custom user model for future safe (to add field and methods later), not for password validator. And where can i add class for extra validation ??   in **Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py** or anywhere elzz ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create new file called passwordValidators.py in project directory and store below code in that.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
import re

class ComplexPasswordValidator:
    """
    Validate whether the password contains minimum one uppercase, one digit and one symbol.
    """
    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.search('[A-Z]', password)==None and re.search('[0-9]', password)==None and re.search('[^A-Za-z0-9]', password)==None:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("This password is not strong."),
                code='password_is_weak',
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _("Your password must contain at least 1 number, 1 uppercase and 1 non-alphanumeric character.")
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
    'NAME': 'dbTest.passwordValidators.ComplexPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Comment: If you want to ensure that the password has at least one of EACH of the password requirements using 'or' in place of 'and' is necessary; otherwise the password will only need to match one of the set of requirements. I had suggested an edit to this answer, but it was declined. The docstring and error message returned from this validator do not match the validation check.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```py
class _ValidatorBase:
    __slots__ = ('message',)
    DEFAULT_MSG = ''

    def __init__(self, message=None):
        self.message = message if message else self.DEFAULT_MSG

    def get_help_text(self):
        return self.message

    def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class HasLowerCaseValidator(_ValidatorBase):
    __slots__ = ()
    DEFAULT_MSG = "The password must contain at least one lowercase character."

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.search('[a-z]', password) is None:
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code='missing_lower_case')


class HasUpperCaseValidator(_ValidatorBase):
    __slots__ = ()
    DEFAULT_MSG = "The password must contain at least one uppercase character."

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.search('[A-Z]', password) is None:
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code='missing_upper_case')


class HasNumberValidator(_ValidatorBase):
    __slots__ = ()
    DEFAULT_MSG = "The password must contain at least one numeric character."

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.search('[0-9]', password) is None:
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code='missing_numeric')


class HasSymbolValidator(_ValidatorBase):
    __slots__ = ()
    DEFAULT_MSG = "The password must contain at least one non-alphanumeric character (symbol)."

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.search('[^A-Za-z0-9]', password) is None:
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code='missing_symbol')
```